# Overhead of In-process function call

Tags: c++, function, oop

According to [Refactoring to Patterns](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/85041)

> Older languages carried an overhead in subroutine calls, which
>   deterred people from small methods. Modern OO languages have pretty
>   much eliminated that overhead for in-process calls.

How have Modern OO languages eliminated this overhead? Is the author referring to inline functions?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 evolutions that reduce/nullify the overhead of function calls:

- CPU evolution:
- Compiler evolution:

Compilers (also based on profile data) can detect where to inline in order to avoid overhead of small function calls, however compiler alone is only 50% of the work:

Modern CPUs are very good at pipelining and prefecteching; most times it is actually more efficient having many small non-inlined functions so that CPU can correctly prefetech and pipeline them instead of many inlined functions that increase binary size and chance for **cache misses**.

Since modern CPUs are very powerfull it is worth trying to organize code better (less maintenance = less work = reduced developing costs) than spending time on microoptimizing it (and microoptimization is much better if done by compiler in almost all cases).

Comment: which cache miss are you talking about instruction or data? Since you mentioned executable size, I assume you are talking about instruction cache

How does increase in executable size lead to instruction cache miss? It may slow down the program due to page fault, though.

Answer (score 2):

I guess so. 
Also, calls are expensive when they require a lot of parameters to be passed via stack. Author mentioned OO languages, in which a lot of parameters may be wrapped in 'this' pointer, which is passed in ecx register (To see more about __thiscall calling convention https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx).

Comment: Good catch, actually resolving 'this' could however lead to a cache miss wich is more costly than passing a dozen parameters

Comment: @kravchenko when you say, a lot of parameters may be wrapped in 'this' pointer, do you mean, that in C++ member functions can access member attributes, and they don't need to be passed as parameter. Did I understand it correctly, or did you mean something else?